# SQL Trigger DATETIME Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to create a trigger in a SQL table that inserts data that passes a condition, [value] = 2, into a separate table. However, I do not want to insert new data from the same source that occurs in the same half hour.

That is, data with [ID] = 1 is inserted into [table1] and passes [value] = 2. This data is then inserted into [table2]. If [ID] = 1 produces another line of data with [value] = 2 in the same half hour, it should not be inserted into [table2].

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[example_trigger] ON [dbo].[table1]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @alert_ID varchar(MAX),
        @alert_created_at datetime2(7),
        @alert_value numeric(8,2)
    SELECT @alert_ID = INSERTED.ID, 
    @alert_created_at = INSERTED.created_at,
    @alert_value = INSERTED.value FROM INSERTED
    IF @alert_value = 2 
    AND @alert_created_at > DATEADD(minute, 30, (SELECT MAX([alert_created_at]) FROM [table2] WHERE @alert_uid = [alert_uid]))
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO table2(alert_uid, alert_created_at, alert_leak_status)
            VALUES(@alert_uid, @alert_created_at, @alert_leak_status)
        END
```

Comment: you should read upon ow to handle triggers https://databasefaqs.com/sql-server-trigger-after-insert/

Comment: That is *not* how you use triggers.

Comment: @Stu, why is this not a valid use of triggers? Seems like a completely acceptable use, placing certain data into a different table after it passes a condition. It does everything it is supposed to do, except the DATEADD line.

Comment: The concept is fine, you should be using `inserted` to inspect the data thats inserted or updated.

Comment: @Stu, I have updated the code block based on your comment. I am new to SQL and Stack Overflow... apologies. Is the update more acceptable?